# zsh syntax highlighting for files

Tags: zsh

I use `zsh-syntax-highlighting` package and it colorize all files with the same color as directories (path). I think one should have possibility to customize these colors or at least use `$LS_COLORS` as default. However it seems that I can change only one variable:

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]='fg=blue,bold'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not a solution, but have you tried to use this: https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS ? It's pretty straightforward and you can customize a lot of file extensions in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question pushed me to [fork](http://github.com/jimmijj/zsh-syntax-highlighting) zsh-syntax-hightighting and add this feature. I've started from the [filetypes](http://github.com/trapd00r/zsh-syntax-highlighting-filetypes) project as ramonovski suggested in the comment, but it is very outdated with respect to original zsh-syntax-highlighting, lacks a lot of feature, supports only "256 color codes" in $LS_COLORS, etc.

At the end I've decided to write my own functions, and the result looks like that:

[image]

Notice a few things:

1. Files (basename) and directories (dirname) are colored differently. This is not like standard `ls` works but I like that better, and to my taste this is just a bug in `ls`.
2. All possible file attributes are taken into account, not only file extension *.xxx. So for example `null` from `/dev/` as a `character device` is yellow here, as in `ls` command.
3. Files without 'special' attributes and without extension are in default color (.zshrc on the picture)
4. Directory names are resolved correctly with tilde

If you like it you can download from github:
http://github.com/jimmijj/zsh-syntax-highlighting