# Apply Colors to Terminal Output to highlight URL & Others

Tags: terminal, osx, colors, oh-my-zsh, color-management

I am looking for a way to apply colors to highlight URLs (http://....) and IP @ in the output of a terminal command.

Example would be with a wget command for example where I would like to be able to output URLs in a particular color so that it is easier to read.

Best would be to be able to do the same for IP@ and other important info to standout.

I have been struggling with this for a while and not able to find a solution.

I use iTerm 2 on MAC with oh-my-zsh

Comment: According to [this blog] (https://gabri.me/blog/custom-colors-in-your-zsh-prompt), if you run `spectrum_ls` in your terminal, do you get the colors?

Comment: I think this is only modifying the prompt color. I am looking for a way to highlight URL and IP @ in any command output.

Answer (score 1):

> **Apply colors to terminal output...**

For anyone looking for a simple way (in my opinion) to color the terminal text in linux

```
# yeah  i know... it's csh... if you need bash the syntax is simply red='<colorcode>'

# i have not experimented with other colors, these have always been enough for me.

setenv RED         '\033[0;31m'
setenv BOLDRED     '\033[1;31m'
setenv GREEN       '\033[0;32m'
setenv BOLDGREEN   '\033[1;32m'
setenv ORANGE      '\033[0;33m'
setenv YELLOW      '\033[1;33m'
setenv BLUE        '\033[0;34m'
setenv BOLDBLUE    '\033[1;34m'
setenv PURPLE      '\033[0;35m'
setenv BOLDPURPLE  '\033[1;35m'
setenv CYAN        '\033[0;36m'
setenv BOLDCYAN    '\033[1;36m'
setenv WHITE       '\033[0,37m'
setenv BOLDWHITE   '\033[1,37m'

# turn color off,  i.e. nocolor
setenv NC          '\033[0m'

# example

echo "${RED}This text is in red.${NC}  This text is now back to whatever the previous color was."

# change my csh/tcsh prompt, and only the prompt, to cyan color that is `[username@host cwd] : ` with all text afterward the default shell color.

set prompt="${CYAN}[%n@%m %~] : ${NC} "
```

*so with the variable setup described above, they can all be local to a bash script for example and you just need to prepend ${COLOR} and append ${NC} to whatever text in your echo statement, or printf, and so on in you bash, csh script or .c or .f program*

Answer (score 0):

On the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154034/zsh-syntax-highlighting-for-files), someone actually [forked](https://github.com/jimmijj/zsh-syntax-highlighting) `zsh-syntax-hightighting` and created a flexible functionality to colorize according to patterns and lot of stuff on zsh.

You might check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script) as well. Don't know if this makes yours a duplicate but oh well. Despite it being old, you can try [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/) as it works with regexp so you can match URL and colorize them.

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced you can set up Triggers; that is, if a certain regular expression is encountered, it might take actions such as highlight the text.

Beware: unfortunately it significantly slows down iTerm.

I'm not sure when this feature appeared, it might be only present in the latest betas.

Comment: Nice. I found the Triggers but putting the following Regex is not working:
^(http|https)://

Comment: Does the URL appear at the beginning of a line, as required by the ^ character in your regexp?

Comment: I am obviously pretty weak on RegEx. I wanted the highlight to happen for any http:// or https:// regardless of where the http:// appears. How should my RegEx look like? 

I tried to remove ^ which works but only highlight the http:// part when I would like this + the URL to be highlight 

http://www.example.com (this shoudl be highlighted anywhere in the output)